# How to display different patterns in same horizontal line?

Tags: java

I have designed different patterns in java and I want then all to print in one single horizontal line. My program is showing the output in vertical line. Here is my code :

```
package demo;

public class PatternDemo {

  public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException {

    int n = 5;

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
      for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ) {
        if ( i == 0 || j == 0 || i == n / 2 || (i <= n / 2 && j == n - 1)
            || i == n - 2 && j == n - 3 || i == n - 1 && j == n - 1 ) {
          System.out.print( "* " );
        } else {
          System.out.print( "  " );
        }

      }
      System.out.println( );

    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
      for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ) {

        if ( i == 0 || j == 0 || j == n - 1 || i == n / 2 ) {
          System.out.print( "* " );
        } else {
          System.out.print( "  " );
        }
      }
      System.out.println( );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What pattern are you trying to generate, and what are you seeing instead?

Comment: I want to print the patterns in one single horizontal line but I am getting them in vertical line.

Comment: @KumariSurabhi Please post an example of what this code should produce and what it is producing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.out.println() will move to next line, After moving you cannot go back to previous line.You have to change the entire logic to get the required pattern

```
    int n= 5;
    for ( int i = 0; i <n; i++) {
        for ( int j = 0; j <n; j++) {
            if(i==0||j==0||i==n/2||(i<=n/2&&j==n-1)||i==n-2&&j==n-3||i==n-1&&j==n-1) {
                System.out.print("* ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

            if(i==0||j==0||j==n-1||i==n/2){
                System.out.print("* ");
            }else {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

**Output:**

```
* * * * * * * * * * 
*       * *       * 
* * * * * * * * * * 
*   *     *       * 
*       * *       *
```

Comment: Can you help, how can I write different logic?

Comment: I already have written the logic and also the output,Check whether it is the required output

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.print()` puts the output immediately after another, with no newline in between them. That is why certain parts come out in the same line. If you want it to print vertically, use `System.out.println()`, which makes the next printed line go to the next line.

Comment: I want to print horizontally .

Comment: Then remove your System.out.println() statements.

Answer (score 0):

The `System.out.println()` statement in your code will always print a line. Maybe removing them can solve your problem.